# Having trouble with my HTML / PHP form

Tags: php, html

Quite new to the game and trying to put together a form and as the title suggests, I'm having no luck.

I wrote the form myself but pinched the php from a tutorial and slightly changed a few things to suit but all that's happening is redirecting to the same page with the "fields1, 2, 3" in my URL.

If anyone has any advice on what to do that'd be amazing!

Cheers,

W

P.S. I'm aware my email says test@email.com too : )

HTML

```
<form>
    <form action="form-to-mail.php" method="POST">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
      <li><label>Full Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" name="field1" class="field-divided" placeholder="First" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="field2" class="field-divided" placeholder="Last" /></li>
      <li>
        <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="field3" class="field-long" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <label>Tell us a little bit about what you do<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="field4" id="field4" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>What are you selling? <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="field5" id="field5" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>How did you hear about FOCUS? <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="field6" id="field6" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
$field3 = $_POST['field3'];
$field4 = $_POST['field4'];
$field5 = $_POST['field5'];
$field6 = $_POST['field6'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
{
echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
echo "Bad email value!";
exit;
}

$email_from = 'test@email.com';
$email_subject = "FOCUS Application";
$email_body = "$field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5, $field6";

$to = "test@email.com";
$headers = "From: <$email_from> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <$visitor_email> \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
 $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't actually say what's happening / going wrong.

Comment: First thing I notice is that you check `isset($_POST['submit'])` but you don't have an element with the name `submit` which you probably want to add to your submit button. You also don't seem to define `$name` or `$visitor_email` before checking them. Finally, instead of IsInjected on email, use [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) to check validity of the address.

Comment: Also, I would not recommend naming your php files with dashes, prefer underscored instead. Ensure the name of your php file which is meant to send the email correspond to the one you wrote in your form attributes.

Comment: You also forgot `exit;` in the first if-statement.

Comment: Sorry @JonStirling I forgot to mention, when I click submit, it reloads the page with the this after the url `/?field1=x&field2=x&field3=lloydstubber%40gmail.com&field4=x&field5=x&field6=x`

I've also changed the file name, added in the other exit but am unsure as to how to define the `$name` or `$visitor_email`. As mentioned, I'm just starting out so this isn't my code.

Thanks in advance!